# Beginning to look at lower level stuff, possibly simply error I don't understand. Buffer Overflow tutorial: Invalid registry 'esp'?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I stumbled across a simple buffer overflow (hey what do you know?) tutorial and thought that I might try it out. The video is about 20 minutes long but it's really interesting, I would recommend watching it if you are not familiar with the stuff. Here's the URL:

http://www.securitytube.net/video/1752

My problem comes in at around 14:17, at that point he inputs a command to look up the stack pointer, but I input the same command, with almost the same code (different memory locations) and get this:

```
(gdb) i r esp
 Invalid register `esp'
```

I don't really know why this is happening, I don't know how it works yet. Did I overwrite the stack pointer or something? I'm running the linux actually through Virtual Box on Windows 7, with the most recent release of Backtrack linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix registers with "$", i. e.

```
i r $esp
```

As you are using a 64 bit gdb, the register name is `$rsp`.

Comment: same one as before "Invalid register `esp'"

Comment: I tried a different name "i r sp" and it did output an address: "sp: 0x7fffffffdde0". Would this be the same as "esp" for me? Why would it be different? (I'm just curious)

Comment: Seems you are running 64 bit code. You should give such an important information in the question the next time. The register name is `rsp` in that case.